# Push .apk to /system/app/ in HTC HERO

Tags: android

I have an HTC HERO and
I need to push my application.apk
 to the /system/app/ folder.

I've followed some tuts on rooting the device
and that is fine, but when I try to push my package to the system/app
folder, I get: "permission denied":

```
$ push /sdcard/myApp.apk /system/app/
push: permission denied
```

I also try:

```
$ su
su
# push /sdcard/myApp.apk /system/app/
push: not found
```

Is this possible in a device that is not a developer intended device?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, running `push` from the device doesn't work as it's not a built-in command.  Ideally you would use the copy command `cp`, but I don't think it's included by default (I've added it to my device via busybox).

Anyway, your problem is that the `/system` partition is mounted as read-only when the device boots.

But if you have root access to the device, you can remount the partition as read-write:

```
host$ adb shell
hero$ su
hero# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
hero# cat /sdcard/myApp.adk > /system/app/myApp.adk
hero# mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Alternatively, after doing the remount, you can use `adb push` from the host as normal.

Comment: I've tried to do that and when reach the cat command, I get:"Cannot create /system/app/: is a directory".
I also tried mv, and I got:"failed on '/sdcard/myApk.apk' - Cross-device link". Is there still some hope? Thaks :)

Comment: Ooops, I originally was using `cp` rather than `cat`. I've fixed the `cat` command line now.

Answer (score 0):

**How I do it:**

```
adb shell 
#su
#mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

open a second terminal and use:

```
adb push myApp.apk /system/app/
```

in first terminal:

```
#reboot
```

What I add more then the others is the reboot - it's a must when doing a remount operation on the Android devices.