# How can I make it so a user can't delete a preinstalled Android app?

Tags: android

If I am an OEM making my own firmware and I want an app preinstalled on the device in a way that it can't be deleted, what do I need to do?

For example, suppose I make the ACME Gadget 2000, and when the user takes it out of the box it already has my app of Cats saying funny things, and I don't want the user to be able to delete it, what exactly do I have to do with the APK?

I have a Verizon Motorola Droid X and it comes with some apps on it that I can't delete.  How do they DO that?

Thank you very much.

David

Comment: Not that this answers your question but if they would root the device they will always be able to remove the app, just something to keep in consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OEM applications that are unremovable are installed to the `/system/app` directory (at least in every case I've ever seen, I suppose there may be exceptions). They cannot be uninstalled (sans rooting the device) because the `/system` partition is mounted read-only by default. I don't know of any way to design an .apk itself to be uninstallable since there are obviously significant security implications to allowing developers to do this.

Example mount listing from a Samsung Fascinate:

> /dev/block/stl9 /system rfs **ro**,relatime,vfat,log_off,check=no,gid/uid/rwx,iochaset=utf8 0 0

Comment: Here are two articles I found that have sets of instructions on how to put an APP into the system/app folder.
http://forum.samdroid.net/f38/move-apps-system-app-1401/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048478/push-apk-to-system-app-in-htc-hero

Answer (score 0):

I mean it's a bit tricky but can be done. You have to allocate `BroadcastReceiver`, which triggered when occurs `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED`, like:

```
 <receiver android:name ="com.mydomain.myapplication.PackageReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>            
              <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And then when you will catch this Intent in your `BroadcastReceiver` - just cancel it. Well, probably you ought to define intent filter priority in a way to receive broadcast before others.

But problem is in simple fact that package which is going to be removed doesn't receive `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED`. That means that you have to keep your own separate application/package which will have service observing who's gonna to uninstall your application.

That's general scheme - but in reality how it'd work - I dunno... Try!