# copy my app .apk to /system/app/ using code

Tags: android

i have read [Push .apk to /system/app/ in HTC HERO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048478/push-apk-to-system-app-in-htc-hero,i) know i can use adb to do this:

```
 host$ adb shell
 hero$ su
 hero# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
 hero# cat /sdcard/myApp.adk > /system/app/myApp.adk
 hero# mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

but my app have root,and i want to use code put my app apk to the  /system/app/,how to do ?

Comment: I m sorry to post here, anyway i cannot post any where, Wish you Happy Birthday Pengwang , My Advance Birthday wishes to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shell commands from the java file

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
out.writeBytes("cat /sdcard/myApp.adk > /system/app/myApp.adk\n");
out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
out.writeBytes("exit\n");  
out.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

This should help you.