# How can I setup a custom WiFi AP or Hotspot with WEP security on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, wifimanager, access-point

I need to setup a WiFi AP with WEP security on an Android Phone or Tablet and I set out to build an App for this purpose.

**Disclaimer:** I am well aware of WEP shortcomings but I still need this. My app is only intended for a handful of people and clearly not meant to be published on Google Play or any other store.

Before I can set it, I tried reading the current configuration using the following piece of code but it fails with the exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: App not allowed to read or update stored
> WiFi Ap config

```
private fun getCurrentConfig(conf: WifiConfiguration) {
    val mGetWifiConfig = wifiManager.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("getWifiApConfiguration")
    return mGetWifiConfig.invoke(wifiManager)
}
```

I have tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>` to `AndroidManifest.xml` to no avail.
My current understanding is that the App needs to be either `system` or `privileged` to be eligible to the relevant permission but I have no clue how to achieve either.

I am using Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1) an currently targeting Api 28, although this it not a requirement and I am flexible here. I'd like my App to be easily installed on reasonably current devices but I'm willing to compromise here as well but I don't want to rely on finding specific vintage devices either.

Answer (score 0):

`android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG` is a system-level permission, meaning that your app has to be signed by a platform key (you would have to create a custom ROM, and sign your app with the same key). Alternatively, you would need to have a rooted phone, and move your app to the system partition.

Comment: is there a way to test this in Android Studio ?

Comment: You can try rooting your emulator, but I have no idea if you'd e able to actually modify any hotspot settings outside of a physical device: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/script-rootavd-root-your-android-studio-virtual-device-emulator-with-magisk-android-12-linux-darwin-macos-win-google-play-store-apis.4218123/

Comment: I'm fine using a physical device, but I have no idea how to "move my app to the system partition", I have currently no way to test my app if I cannot get past the point where the permission is required

Comment: You have to root your phone, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007024/push-my-apk-to-system-app